# Why does the edit method of an embedded Word object in Visio change?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-visio

In Microsoft Visio, one can insert a Microsoft Word object (Insert / Text / Object / "Microsoft Word Document").

Most of the time when I do this, when I later go to edit the content of that Word document, a Word application is launched. I edit the content using Word.

However, in one Visio document, when I go to edit a Word object, instead of launching Word, a strange editor opens up in Visio.

What is the cause of this variety?

SOLUTION: Right click the object > Click "Document Object" > Click "Open".
This opens the document in Word, so you can edit it easily.

Comment: Have you tried to right click the object > Document Object > Convert, then convert the Word document again? Please note, backup the document first,

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
OK, so doing that did not make a difference. However, while doing it, I noticed the "Open" option. I had never noticed that before. Clicking that, the document opens in Word so I can edit it.

Thanks again!